# Perfect forward to an intermediate reference object before forwarding to an expensive constructor

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function `foo` that receives a forwarding/universal reference and I would like to hold that reference in a short-lived object, `key`, which I then pass to a third-party library that will evaluate whether or not it is necessary to construct a heavier object, `heavy`, and then perfectly forward the held reference from within `key` to `heavy`.

Assume this library has a function `emplace` that knows to construct `heavy` in place from `key`.

E.g., something like:

```cpp
// template <class T> ??
struct key {
    key(auto&& arg) : _ref(???), _v(proccess(arg)) {}

    ?? _ref{};
    int _v{};   // used by third-party library to evaluate whether to construct `heavy`
};

struct heavy {
    heavy(key&& k) : 
      _expensive( ??? (k._ref) ),  // should be equivalent to as if `key` was never created
                                   // and instead we called:
                                   //    Expensive(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg))
                                   // Assuming Expensive has a forwarding ref overload
      _v(k._v) {}
    
    Expensive _expensive{};
    int _v{};
};

void foo(auto&& arg) {
    container<heavy> c;

    c.emplace(key{std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg)}); // may or may not actually decide 
                                                      // to create `heavy`
}
```

I'm a little stumped on if this is at all possible...

Edit: the only things I cannot change are the implementation of `container` and `Expensive` in the above example. `key` does not necessarily have to be done in the way shown but I need to be able to pass the `int _v` along with `_ref` to `container`

Comment: You cannot forward through a class member.

Comment: @NathanOliver if so, is there an alternative way to do this and sort of hold a reference "for a bit" before carrying on with constructing `heavy`?

Comment: You could pack the references with [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple)

Comment: @supernun There might be but one issue you will have is that temporary objects are destroyed at the end of the full expression they are in.  If you are going to have expressions between the create and the emplacement then this will cause issues unless you are going down into a call stack (keep passing the value down the chain until it is used).  One widely used option is to use smart pointers (namely `unique_ptr`).  This lets you create the object once and then you can just move the pointer around to where it is needed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo mind elaborating? I haven't used `forward_as_tuple` before.

Comment: @NathanOliver in this case, temporary or not, it will exist at least until the emplace call is completed. If I understood correctly, the `unique_ptr` idea requires that I create `heavy` up front, which is what Im trying to avoid. Unless I misunderstood you

Comment: `forward_as_tuple`: _"Constructs a tuple of references to the arguments in args suitable for forwarding as an argument to a function"_

Comment: I don't quite get this: "evaluate whether to construct `heavy`" - if it's already in there, `heavy` will be constructed (unless `key` `throw`s)

Comment: @TedLyngmo consider something like this: https://abseil.io/tips/144 to avoid creating an object prior to checking if you need to ahead of time.

Comment: That uses a transparent comparator in order to not have to create `std::string`s when searching. I'm not sure how that applies here. Perhaps you could elaborate by making your example a little closer to what your real code looks?

Comment: @TedLyngmo its almost exactly like I have in the question. I left out that the container takes additional template parameters to transparently compare `key` and `heavy`.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand the pseudo language. `_expensive( ??? (k._ref) )` - what should happen if `???` is `true`/`false`/`something else`? The transparent comparator doesn't explain that.

Comment: by the ??? I mean to ask... "what should I do here with the `k._ref` to pass what was previously `arg` down to `Expensive`'s ctor.

Comment: ... and how should _"evaluate whether to construct `heavy`"_ be treated here? It's too late to stop the construction of `heavy` (if you don't `throw`).

Comment: the "evaluate" part is done by the third party library _before_ constructing `heavy`. It will first check `key._v` and if that satisfies some condition, then actually go ahead and construct `heavy` from `key`, else return without creating `heavy`.
e.g. with transparent containers: ```if (c.find(key_obj) == c.end()) { c.insert(heavy{key_obj});}``` but that requires two "searches". I'm hoping to have just a single search operation that constructs `heavy` only if not found.

Comment: This is just a start of something, but is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/PEr767svb) something like what you'd like? I still think I'd need more context to make a proper answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah thats what Im going for. The library I'm using would take that tuple in the call to `emplace` and basically do the "find or emplace" you're doing there but without doing the search twice (as would happen in `std::set`). If the element wasn't found, it would use the tuple to construct `heavy` in place. I think you basically have it but with using that tuple in place of `key` in my example code.

Comment: Can you clarify, in the above, which parts of the code are you allowed to change? Everything except the implementation of `container`?

Comment: @BrianBi updated with an edit

Comment: Give a minimal example that compile and works as expected except for the undesired call to the heavy construction. Provide also the case where heavy function call is required.

Comment: If you want to use perfect forwarding, then shouldn't `heavy` have a constructor that takes `const key&`  in addition to the one that takes `key&&`?